# Brushless DC motor power over rpm

Tags: power, brushless-dc-motor, rpm

I am trying to get my head around how to theoretically describe the relationship between power and rpm of a brushless DC motor. I want to do this to check which motors from a list of available ones are capable to drive a specific load. Here is what I found out so far:

1. In general a brushless DC motor (which is a synchronous motor) will always provide the power demanded by a load. This statement can't be entirely true because there must be limitations on the power the motor can provide at a specific speed. This limit is what I am looking for.

---

2. The rpm of the motor is set by the frequency of the supplied voltage

---

3. If a load demands more torque at a specific rpm the rotor will lag behind of the rotating magnetic field. This is possible up until the rotor lags behind more than 90 degrees. At this point the rotor goes out of synchronization with the field and the motor stalls. This is the pull-out torque and it sets a limit on the maximum power providable by the motor.

---

4. The rotor induces voltages in the windings which has to be overcome by the ESC. This voltage increases with the rpm of the rotor and thus sets a limit on the maximum rpm achivable (commonly refered to as no-load rpm)

---

5. The torque is (roughly) proportional to the current in the stator when disregarding saturation.

All of this boiled down to one equation for the power

`P(omega) = omega * 1/K_v * 1/R_internal * (U_supply - omega/K_v)`

where `P` is power in W, `omega` is the angular velocity of the motor in rad/s, `K_v` is the motor speed constant in rad/(V * s), `R_internal` is the internal resistance of a winding in Ohm and `U_supply` is the supply voltage in V.

The problem now is, this does not always match with the specs that are provided by suppliers. For example for a motor with speed constant 80 rpm/V, internal resistance of 0.16 Ohm and supply voltage of 70 V, the rated power (provided by the supplier) is 7.5kW but the maximum in this power model is at 800W.

The motor "specifications" are [here](https://www.freerchobby.cc/products/frc-15kw-mp12090-brushless-dc-outrunner-motor-with-40kg-thrust-for-electric-paramotor?variant=34842241237153).

[image: Plot of power over rpm]

Where does this discrepancy come from? Is there an error in the model? Where can I find information on modeling the power a BLDC can provide.

Comment: Can you include a link to the reference you are citing? If you copied this directly is it possible the 8kW spec is really .8kW (a missing decimal)?  Or could it be 8Kv which for a BLDC motor refers to the motor's velocity constant.  For the later possibility see: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-kv-uav-bldc-motor-vectortechnics

Comment: @Nedd Thanks for the heads up. I added the link to the post.